# Adding one handler with different parameters

Tags: javascript

I am creating elements in list tag dynamically and I want to add different event handler for all elements in list. How can I achieve this?

```
var menuLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    for(var j = 0; j < menuLinks.length; j++)
    {
        var menuLink = menuLinks[j];
        menuLink.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(menuLink.innerHTML);
        };
    }
```

I added the elements in class name test but no matter which ever element I click it always gives me last element.

Comment: You simply iterate over the elements and add the handlers? Please elaborate.

Comment: I created elements dynamically. The problem is that when I add event handler, it only calls the handler of the last element in the list even if I click on the first element.

Comment: Then you are probably doing something wrong. Please post your code. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a closure inside a loop. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for an explanation and generic solution.

In short: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Since there is only a single `menuLink` variable, every handler refers to that one variable. The variable can of course only have one value, which is the one that is set in the last iteration.

---

However, in your case there is a simpler solution: You can use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the element. You don't need to rely on the loop variable:

```
menuLinks[j].onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
};
```

[Learn more about `this` in event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var menuLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
        for(var j = 0; j < menuLinks.length; j++)
        {
            var menuLink = menuLinks[j];
            menuLink.onclick = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
            };
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP uses jQuery?